# Returning values from a custom dialog view

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to make a custom dialog for my android application. I get null pointer exceptions when I attempt to access the fields from the 'ok' button method. It seems like my fields fade from existence as soon as the onclick listener fires. Is there a better way to do this?

```
addchars.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/scrollBox">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/addChars">
    <AutoCompleteTextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/inCharName" android:hint="@string/txtCharacterNameBox" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtHP" android:layout_below="@+id/inCharName" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtTempHP" android:layout_below="@+id/inCharName" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="57dp"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inHP" android:digits="-0123456789" android:minEms="3" android:gravity="center" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2">
    </EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inTempHP" android:digits="0123456789" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inHP" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inHP" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/inHP" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inHP" android:text="@string/txtInitRoll"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/inTempHP" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inTempHP" android:text="@string/txtInitBonus"></TextView>
    <EditText android:digits="0123456789" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/inInitRoll"></EditText>
    <EditText android:digits="0123456789" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView02" android:id="@+id/inInitBonus"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/txtAC" android:layout_below="@+id/inInitRoll" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inAC" android:digits="0123456789" android:gravity="center" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView03"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/inAC" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inInitBonus" android:text="@string/txtFortitude"></TextView>
    <EditText android:digits="0123456789" android:gravity="center" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView04" android:id="@+id/inFort"></EditText>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/inFort" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inFort" android:text="@string/txtWill"></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/inAC" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inAC" android:text="@string/txtRef"></TextView>
    <EditText android:digits="0123456789" android:gravity="center" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inInitRoll" android:id="@+id/inReflex"></EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inWill" android:digits="0123456789" android:gravity="center" android:minEms="3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="phone" android:maxLength="2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/chkRoll" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView06"></EditText>
    <CheckBox android:text="@string/txtRollBox" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chkRoll" android:layout_below="@+id/inReflex" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></CheckBox>
</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

And this is my alertdialog:

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //this block is to prep the layout for the alert dialog.
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addchars, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.scrollBox));


            //taking this part out to try a better way.

            new AlertDialog.Builder(initiative.this)
            .setTitle("Add a Character")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    //ui controls
                    AutoCompleteTextView characterName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.inCharName);
                    EditText hp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inHP); 
                    EditText tempHp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inTempHP);
                    EditText initRoll = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inInitRoll);
                    EditText initBonus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inInitBonus);
                    EditText ac = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inAC); 
                    EditText fort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inFort);
                    EditText reflex = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inReflex);
                    EditText will = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inWill);
                    CheckBox rollInit = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkRoll);

                    //variables for various checks
                    entriesOk=false;
                    needToRoll=false;


                    if(characterName.getText().length() > 0)
                    {
                        holdCharacterName = characterName.getText().toString();
                        if(hp.getText().length() > 0)
                        {
                            holdHp = hp.getText().toString();
                            if(initBonus.getText().length() > 0)
                            {

                                holdInitBonus = initBonus.getText().toString();

                                if(ac.getText().length() > 0)
                                {
                                    holdAc = ac.getText().toString();
                                    if(fort.getText().length() > 0)
                                    {
                                        holdFort = fort.getText().toString();
                                        if(reflex.getText().length() > 0)
                                        {
                                            holdReflex = reflex.getText().toString();
                                            if(will.getText().length() > 0)
                                            {
                                                holdWill = will.getText().toString();
                                                if(tempHp.getText().length() == 0)
                                                {
                                                    holdTempHp = "0";
                                                    tempHp.setText("0");
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    holdTempHp = tempHp.getText().toString();
                                                }

                                                if(rollInit.isChecked())
                                                {
                                                    entriesOk = true;
                                                    needToRoll = true;
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    if(initRoll.getText().length() > 0)
                                                    {
                                                        holdInitRoll = initRoll.getText().toString();
                                                        entriesOk = true;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    btnLogic();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }).show();
```

Comment: I would combine a few of those if statements, it would be easier to follow...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto I was a bit concerned with which fields weren't completed in an earlier draft of this. I'll try to clean it up, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addView.findViewById(R.id.inHP)` instead of `findViewById(R.id.inHP)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling addView.findViewById inside your onClick event, the onclick doesn't really happen until somebody clicks on it, I'll suggest that you make addView class member variable so that it can persist in memory. That'll solve your problem.